# Cameras and ITrackableObjects

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net, interface

The purpose of these two classes (and hence why I am including them together) is to allow you to create a `Camera`, that indicates a "render zone", and track an object in this `Camera`, so that when the `Position` of the `ITrackableObject` changes, the `Camera.Position` changes to reflect that.

Ignore the unimplemented `Camera.CenterCamera(float animationTime)` method, I've yet to decide what to do with it.

GitHub link to this version: [`Camera`](https://github.com/EBrown8534/Framework/blob/ea64acb0a397b5b4f5bdaeda3c57bded1e384a85/Evbpc.Framework/Utilities/Camera.cs), [`ITrackableObject`](https://github.com/EBrown8534/Framework/blob/49fbb742d84a9f290f62fc69489fb578183dd99d/Evbpc.Framework/Utilities/ITrackableObject.cs), [`PositionChangedEventArgs`](https://github.com/EBrown8534/Framework/blob/24deb3b9329a97d6459e92c934e2397209fb34d8/Evbpc.Framework/Utilities/PositionChangedEventArgs.cs).

The `Camera` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an object that tracks and updates it's position based on another object, and can be used to determine where rendering should take place.
/// </summary>
public class Camera : ITrackableObject
{
    private PointF _Position;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="ITrackableObject"/> that is being tracked by this <see cref="Camera"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    public ITrackableObject TrackObject { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="PointF"/> that is the current location of this <see cref="Camera"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    public PointF Position { get { return _Position; } private set { if (_Position != value) { var oldPosition = _Position; _Position = value; OnPositionChanged(new PositionChangedEventArgs(oldPosition, _Position)); } } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="SizeF"/> of this <see cref="Camera"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    public SizeF Size { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <code>float</code> value that represents how this <see cref="Camera"/> instance should scale (or zoom). A value of <code>1.0f</code> is the default, and indicates that it should not be zoomed.
    /// </summary>
    public float Scale { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="RectangleF"/> that represents how close to the edge of the <see cref="Bounds"/> an <see cref="ITrackableObject"/> must be for the <see cref="Camera"/> to pan.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The values for this <see cref="RectangleF"/> represent the percentage of difference between the center of the <see cref="Camera.Bounds"/> and the edge of the <see cref="Camera.Bounds"/>. A value of <c>0.5</c> in each field will mean that the centre 50% of the screen will pan about.
    /// 
    /// This value cannot be set directly as it could cause the <see cref="Camera"/> to "jump" very quickly, and create a graphics issue. If you wish to change this value you should create a new instance of the <see cref="Camera"/> class.
    /// </remarks>
    public RectangleF TriggerBounds { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="RectangleF"/> that represents the entire covered portion of this <see cref="Camera"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    public RectangleF Bounds { get { return new RectangleF(Position, Size); } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="PointF"/> that represents the global center position of this <see cref="Camera"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    public PointF AbsoluteCenter { get { return new PointF(Position.X + Size.Width / 2f, Position.Y + Size.Height / 2f); } }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="PointF"/> that represents the center of the <see cref="Size"/> of this <see cref="Camera"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    public PointF RelativeCenter { get { return new PointF(Size.Width / 2f, Size.Height / 2f); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the <see cref="Camera"/> class from the specified <see cref="TrackObject"/> and <see cref="TriggerBounds"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="trackObject">An <see cref="ITrackableObject"/> to follow.</param>
    /// <param name="triggerBounds">A <see cref="RectangleF"/> that represents how close to the edge of the screen an <see cref="ITrackableObject"/> must be to trigger panning.</param>
    public Camera(ITrackableObject trackObject, RectangleF triggerBounds)
    {
        if (trackObject == null || trackObject == this)
            throw new ArgumentException("The trackObject must not be null or this instance.");

        TrackObject = trackObject;
        TriggerBounds = triggerBounds;

        if (trackObject != null)
            trackObject.PositionChanged += trackObject_PositionChanged;
    }

    private void trackObject_PositionChanged(object sender, PositionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // We should make the new camera position the same as the position of the entity, minus the centering
        _Position = new PointF((TrackObject.Position.X + TrackObject.Size.Width) / 2.0f - RelativeCenter.X, (TrackObject.Position.Y + TrackObject.Size.Height) / 2.0f - RelativeCenter.Y);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will <b>immediately</b> move the <see cref="Camera"/> to center on the <see cref="ITrackableObject"/>. If you wish to pan smoothly, you should use <see cref="CenterCamera(float)"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This is effectively the same as the <see cref="CenterCamera(float)"/> method with an value of <c>0</c> specified.
    /// </remarks>
    public void CenterCamera() { CenterCamera(0); }
    /// <summary>
    /// This method will smoothly center the <see cref="Camera"/> to the <see cref="ITrackableObject"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="animationTime">A value that indicates how long (in seconds) it should take the <see cref="Camera"/> to center on the <see cref="ITrackableObject"/>. Smaller values will mean a quicker movement, but may also cause jumpy-ness.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// If a value of <c>0</c> is provided for the <c>animationTime</c>, then this has the same effect as the <see cref="CenterCamera()"/> method.
    /// </remarks>
    public void CenterCamera(float animationTime) { /* TODO: Implement this method. */ }
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the <see cref="Position"/> of the current <see cref="Camera"/> instance to the value specified.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="position">A <see cref="PointF"/> representing the new <see cref="Position"/> of the <see cref="Camera"/>.</param>
    public void SetPosition(PointF position) { Position = position; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Alters the <see cref="Position"/> of the current <see cref="Camera"/> instance by the specified <see cref="Vector2F"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vector">The distance to move the <see cref="Camera"/>.</param>
    public void MoveCamera(Vector2F vector) { Position = new PointF(Position.X + vector.X, Position.Y + vector.Y); }
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the <see cref="Size"/> of the current <see cref="Camera"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="size">A <see cref="SizeF"/> representing the new <see cref="Size"/> of the <see cref="Camera"/>.</param>
    public void SetSize(SizeF size) { Size = size; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Alters the <see cref="Size"/> of the current <see cref="Camera"/> instance by the specified <see cref="Vector2F"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="adjustment">The <see cref="Vector2F"/> representing how much to increase/decrease the <see cref="Size"/>.</param>
    public void ResizeCamera(Vector2F adjustment) { Size = new SizeF(Size.Width + adjustment.X, Size.Height + adjustment.Y); }
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the <see cref="Scale"/> of the current <see cref="Camera"/> instance to the specified value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="scale">The new value for the <see cref="Scale"/> value of the <see cref="Camera"/>.</param>
    public void SetScale(float scale) { Scale = scale; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Alters the <see cref="Scale"/> of the current <see cref="Camera"/> instance by the specified value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="adjustment">The value representing how much to zoom/unzoom the <see cref="Camera"/>.</param>
    public void ScaleCamera(float adjustment) { Scale += adjustment; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines if the current <see cref="Camera"/> instances contains the <see cref="ITrackableObject"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="testObject">The <see cref="ITrackableObject"/> to test.</param>
    /// <param name="entirelyContained">If true, will only return true if the testObject is entirely contained in the <see cref="Camera.Bounds"/>, otherwise will return true if any part of the testObject is contained.</param>
    /// <returns>If entirelyContained is true, returns true only if the entire testObject is contained within <see cref="Camera.Bounds"/>. If entirelyContained is false, returns true if any part of the testObject is contained within <see cref="Camera.Bounds"/>.</returns>
    public bool Contains(ITrackableObject testObject, bool entirelyContained)
    {
        if (entirelyContained)
            return Bounds.Contains(new RectangleF(testObject.Position, testObject.Size));
        else
        {
            if (Bounds.Contains(testObject.Position))
                return true;

            if (Bounds.Contains(testObject.Position.X, testObject.Size.Height))
                return true;

            if (Bounds.Contains(testObject.Size.Width, testObject.Position.Y))
                return true;

            if (Bounds.Contains(testObject.Size.Width, testObject.Size.Height))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void OnPositionChanged(PositionChangedEventArgs e) { var handler = PositionChanged; if (handler != null) { handler(this, e); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// An event that may be subscribed to for notification of when the <see cref="Position"/> property of this <see cref="Camera"/> instance changes.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<PositionChangedEventArgs> PositionChanged;
}
```

And the `ITrackableObject` interface:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides an interface to be used for tracking the position of an object, in classes similar to the <see cref="Camera"/> class.
/// </summary>
public interface ITrackableObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the position of the <see cref="ITrackableObject"/>.
    /// </summary>
    PointF Position { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the size of the <see cref="ITrackableObject"/>.
    /// </summary>
    SizeF Size { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// An event that objects tracking the current <see cref="ITrackableObject"/> can subscribe to in order to receive notifications of changes to the <see cref="Position"/>.
    /// </summary>
    event EventHandler<PositionChangedEventArgs> PositionChanged;
}
```

Finally, `PositionChangedEventArgs`:

```
public class PositionChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private PointF _NewPosition;
    private PointF _OldPosition;

    public PointF NewPosition { get { return _NewPosition; } }
    public PointF OldPosition { get { return _OldPosition; } }

    public PositionChangedEventArgs(PointF mNewPosition, PointF mOldPosition) { _NewPosition = mNewPosition; _OldPosition = mOldPosition; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have to check this a second time

> ```
>     if (trackObject != null)
>         trackObject.PositionChanged += trackObject_PositionChanged;
> ```

you already check to make sure it is not null here

> ```
>     if (trackObject == null || trackObject == this)
>         throw new ArgumentException("The trackObject must not be null or this instance.");
> ```

you could probably get rid of the if statement there.

---

This

> ```
>         if (Bounds.Contains(testObject.Position))
>             return true;
>
>         if (Bounds.Contains(testObject.Position.X, testObject.Size.Height))
>             return true;
>
>         if (Bounds.Contains(testObject.Size.Width, testObject.Position.Y))
>             return true;
>
>         if (Bounds.Contains(testObject.Size.Width, testObject.Size.Height))
>             return true;
> ```

could probably be turned into one single if statement

```
if (Bounds.Contains(testObject.Position) 
    || Bounds.Contains(testObject.Position.X, testObject.Size.Height)
    || Bounds.Contains(testObject.Size.Width, testObject.Position.Y) 
    || Bounds.Contains(testObject.Size.Width, testObject.Size.Height))
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I wrote the `if (trackObject == null || trackObject == this)` bit today, and the `if (trackObject != null)` bit weeks ago and completely forgot it was there. :)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> public bool Contains(ITrackableObject testObject, bool entirelyContained)
> {
>     if (entirelyContained)
>         return Bounds.Contains(new RectangleF(testObject.Position, testObject.Size));
>     else
>     {
>         if (Bounds.Contains(testObject.Position))
>             return true;
>
>         if (Bounds.Contains(testObject.Position.X, testObject.Size.Height))
>             return true;
>
>         if (Bounds.Contains(testObject.Size.Width, testObject.Position.Y))
>             return true;
>
>         if (Bounds.Contains(testObject.Size.Width, testObject.Size.Height))
>             return true;
>     }
>
>     return false;
> }
> ```

You don't need the `else` statement because you return from the `if`.

@Malachi says you can merge the `if`s in the `else` into one `if` statement, and that is true, although I don't recommend it for readability purposes.  However, if you do that, you don't even need the `if` statement to return true - just combine it all into a return statement:

```
return Bounds.Contains(testObject.Position) 
    || Bounds.Contains(testObject.Position.X, testObject.Size.Height)
    || Bounds.Contains(testObject.Size.Width, testObject.Position.Y) 
    || Bounds.Contains(testObject.Size.Width, testObject.Size.Height));
```

Additionally, I recommend putting braces around your `if` statements.  They won't prevent bugs, but they will help prevent bugs.

Comment: I keep forgetting about my early returns. And I'd rather not combine them all into one statement, as it does get a bit cumbersome. :)